# Is there a better method to factoring large polynomials such as $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

The question is as such:

> Express $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ in irreducible factors $\in \mathbb{R}$

My initial thoughts to this were to use grouping of factors but this method was to no avail. Instead, I took this detour:

$x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is a factor of $x^7 - 1$, that is $x^7 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$

Hence, we can factor $x^7 - 1$ instead and just eliminate $x = 1$.

$$\to x^7 - 1 = 0$$

$$\to x^7 = 1 = e^{i2\pi}$$

$$\to x = e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{7}}, k = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$$

$$\to x^7 - 1 = (x - 1)(x - e^{i\frac{2\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{4\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{6\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{8\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{10\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{12\pi}{7}})$$

Finally we have, $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = (x - e^{i\frac{2\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{4\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{6\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{8\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{10\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{12\pi}{7}})$.

After a bit more thought, we can obtain real factors by group two factors such that upon multiplication, the angle addition obtains $e^{\frac{14\pi}{7}} = 1$, as the $c$ in $x^2 + bx + c$. This would be like $(x - e^{i\frac{2\pi}{7}})(x - e^{i\frac{12\pi}{7}}) = x^2 - 2\sin(\frac{3\pi}{14})x + 1$ (Using $e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}$).

Of course, all of this is tedious by hand to work out and type here, hence my final output was $$x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = (x^2 - 2\sin(\frac{3\pi}{14})x + 1)(x^2 + 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})x + 1)(x^2 + 2\sin(\frac{\pi}{14}) + 1)$$.

**My Question:**

Is this factoring correct, and more importantly is there a more direct/simpler way to factor the polynomial?

Comment: @DietrichBurde so there would be no other possible method?

Comment: People use calculus for sums of powers of $\zeta=\zeta_7$. So grouping together conjugate pairs, a factorization of the polynomial $\; 1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6\;$ is also the following:

$\begin{align}
&1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=\\
&=\left[1-2z\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)+z^2\right]\cdot\left[1-2z\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}\right)+z^2\right]\cdot\\
&\cdot\left[1-2z\cos\left(\dfrac{6\pi}{7}\right)+z^2\right]
\end{align}$

Comment: @Dstarred The factoring is not correct, see the comment by Dietrich Burde.

Comment: @PierreCarre thank you, I incorrectly ommitted the negative in front of $2\sin{\frac{\pi}{14}}$ the in the last factor.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another well-known method is to rewrite the polynomial as follows.

$\begin{align}
&1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=\\
&=z^3\left(\dfrac{1}{z^3}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{z}+1+z+z^2+z^3\right)=\\
&=z^3\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{z^3}+z^3\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{z^2}+z^2\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)+1\right]=\\
&=z^3\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)^3-3\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)^2-2+\\
+\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)+1\right]=\\
&=z^3\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)^3+\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+z\right)-1\right].
\end{align}$

By letting $\;y=\dfrac{1}{z}+z\;$ we get that

$\begin{align}
&1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=z^3\left(y^3+y^2-2y-1\right).
\end{align}$
Now consider the real roots of the polynomial $\;y^3+y^2-2y-1\;$, which all belong to the interval $\;\left]-2,2\right[\; .$

Comment: Nice manipulation, this is much simpler in my view. I see that the roots correspond to the coefficients of the $x$ terms in the original factors?

Comment: $+1,$ very nice solution!

Comment: I haven’t seen technique this in a while. Very nice!